Better way to filter an array of objects with one constant and one always changing value
I am currently looking for a better way to filter my array of objects to avoid duplicate my code again and again.
Here is my example array:
arr = [
{
"no": 11145,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R1",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 14568,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R1",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 24562,
"stringers": "P2",
"ribs": "R9",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 658741,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R2",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 325690,
"stringers": "P4",
"ribs": "R5",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 9745201,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R2",
"description": "some text"
},
.....
]

Currently I am filtering the array like that:
let p1r1 = arr.filter(function(el){
  return el.stringers === "P1" && el.ribs === "R1"
})
let p1r2 = arr.filter(function(el){
  return el.stringers === "P1" && el.ribs === "R2"
})
// ...and so on

This results in a lot of lines where I repeat the same code over and over (except for the changing ribs value). Is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Same way you'd deduplicate any code; write a function, e.g. let p1r1 = filter_by_ribs(arr, "R1").

Having numbered variable names is a bit suspicious in itself; consider if a data structure would be more suitable, like a Map where the keys look like "p1r1". (And then look at Map.groupBy.)

You could take an object as result with the wanted keys as groups.


const
    data = [{ no: 11145, stringers: "P1", ribs: "R1", description: "some text" }, { no: 14568, stringers: "P1", ribs: "R1", description: "some text" }, { no: 24562, stringers: "P2", ribs: "R9", description: "some text" }, { no: 658741, stringers: "P1", ribs: "R2", description: "some text" }, { no: 325690, stringers: "P4", ribs: "R5", description: "some text" }, { no: 9745201, stringers: "P1", ribs: "R2", description: "some text" }],
    result = Object.groupBy(data, ({ stringers, ribs }) => stringers + ribs);

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




You can use array map to get just the ribs value.
arr.map(a => a.ribs); // [R1, R2, R1...]

A set is like an array, but only of unique values.
new Set(arr.map(a => a.ribs))

I like using array functions, so I cast that back to an array
const uniqueRibs = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(a => a.ribs)))

Now we can do anything with that.
uniqueRibs.forEach(ribs => console.log(arr.filter(a => a.ribs == ribs)))

Runnable example:


const arr = [
{
"no": 11145,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R1",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 14568,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R1",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 24562,
"stringers": "P2",
"ribs": "R9",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 658741,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R2",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 325690,
"stringers": "P4",
"ribs": "R5",
"description": "some text"
},
{
"no": 9745201,
"stringers": "P1",
"ribs": "R2",
"description": "some text"
},
]

Array.from(new Set(arr.map(a => a.ribs))).forEach(ribs => {
  console.log(`Ribs with value ${ribs}`);
  console.log(arr.filter(a => a.ribs == ribs));
});



